# Azure Data Factory send failed notifications to teams channel

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, microsoft-teams

I need help on how do I send Azure Data Factory(ADF) Start, Success or Failure notification within ADF using Web activity.

I searched a lot but found articles relates to sending email notifications through ADF, but no article found which talks about sending these Start, Success or Failure notification to MS-Teams channel.

NOTE : I already have created MS-Teams channel and I have links associated with this channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please take a look at [Webhooks and Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors)?. Connectors allow you to post the notifications from an external service to the Teams channel. You can build your own connector by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating) guide.